# Is this a good way to retrieve data from an API?

Tags: c#

Could someone tell me if this is a good way to retrieve data from an API?
I'm new to this, and wonder if someone could recommend me some kind of setup and structure, and if this could be done in a more correct way?

```
string baseUrl = "https://api.data.com/getITems/
//Create a new instance of HttpClient
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
    using (HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl))
    using (HttpContent content = result.Content)
    {
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var test1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Results>(data);

        foreach (var item in test1.results)
        {
            foreach (var item1 in item.result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", item1.Symbol);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: u might wanna look at restsharp http://restsharp.org/

Comment: You generally don't want to new-up an instance of `HttpClient`, if you'd go on and use it often. You're better of storing an instance of `HttpClient` in a static variable.

Comment: also great tool  [RestEase](https://github.com/canton7/RestEase)

Comment: I disagree with the comment of @Marco. Neither do I think immediately opening a HTTP client and disposing after use is a bad habit, neither do I like static variables, especially when it comes to complex objects that use TCP connections and the like. How about concurrency in your suggestion, @Marco?

Comment: I stand corrected: [Static and concurrency with (most) HTTP client methods seems to be OK](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69954/1996).

Comment: [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. You could use a nuget package to simplify some of the operations or turn it into a helper class. The only thing you should do differently is not create a new `HttpClient` every time, this is against the practices. You should only create it once and use it lots of times.

Comment: How can I do this? I want to split the console application in a more structured filestructure. Any recommendation?

Comment: Your code calls a URL, gets some data, and deserializes it into an object. You could write some generic code that lets you do that for any URL, and any data, and just call it whenever you need it. There are nuget libraries that do some of this, you'd have to search but as mentioned, RestSharp is one of them. But it shouldn't be hard to do it yourself into a separate class. You might need to use Generics for some of it.

Comment: Where should I put the url and username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Deciding if your implementation is a good way, is out of my scope, since I do not know your requirements and genereally you can always extract some functionality into some other class, while juggeling the effort you put in against the expected value you get out of it.

That being said, I'll just go into the one thing that springs to my eye and that is your usage of `HttpClient` itself.

If this is a long lived application and you keep calling that part of your code, you will always new-up an new instance of `HttpClient` and then dispose it. This will kill the connections to your endpoint immediately, but leave the ports in `TIME_WAIT` state. 
Do this is a couple of hundred or thousand times and you will most likely run into `SocketException`, because your machine has run out of available sockets to use.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client):

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout
>   the life of an application.

If all HttpClients, share the same headers and base address, you can re-use a single instance of that client throughout your application. If you have different headers, create a new static client.
In both scenarios you want to use them as a singleton throughout your application.

Some further reading:

- https://medium.com/@nuno.caneco/c-httpclient-should-not-be-disposed-or-should-it-45d2a8f568bc
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client
- https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69950/single-instance-of-reusable-httpclient/69954#69954

Comment: Sure. Every DI framework should be able to handle this

Comment: What do you recommend me to do? Use Resharp?

Comment: does this looks fine?

Bind<HttpClient>().To<HttpClient>();

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ninject